# Play 1.2.2 - are tags inside tags no longer allowed?

Tags: java, templates, playframework

I am developing an application in play and in my selenium tests I use several tags for repetitive tasks. Two tags are:

**app/views/tags/loginAs.html**

```
*{ Tag for running selenium tests when being logged in }*

#{if !_keepData}
#{braindumpFixture delete:'all', load:'users.yml' /}
#{/if}

#{selenium}
 ... some selenium code to log into the application
#{/selenium}
```

**app/views/tags/braindumpFixture.html**

```
%{
if(_delete == 'all') {
play.test.Fixtures.deleteAll()
} else if(_delete) {
play.test.Fixtures.delete(_delete)
}
}%

%{
if(_load) {
play.test.Fixtures.load(_load)
}
// finally make sure the index is correctly updated.
new application.jobs.CompleteReindexJob().doJob();
}%
```

These work without a problem in Play 1.1. After switching to play 1.2.2, I get the following exception when running a selenium test that uses loginAs:

**test/selenium/AddCard.test.html**

```
*{ Tests adding a simple card }*

#{loginAs login:'foobar@foobar.com', password:'foobar' /}

#{selenium}
open('@{Application.index()}')
... more selenium stuff here
#{/selenium}
```

The exception being:

```
play.exceptions.TemplateExecutionException: Cannot get property 'data' on null object
    at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:84)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:252)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate$ExecutableTemplate.invokeTag(GroovyTemplate.java:374)
    at /test/selenium/AddCard.test.html.(line:3)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:229)
    at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:184)
    at controllers.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:107)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:543)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:499)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:475)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:470)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:158)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'data' on null object
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:229)
    ... 12 more
```

When I remove the #{if !_keepData} around the call to braindumpFixture I get an EmptyStackException:

```
play.exceptions.TemplateExecutionException
    at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:84)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:252)
    at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:184)
    at controllers.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:107)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:543)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:499)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:475)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:470)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:158)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:85)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:67)
    at play.templates.TagContext.exitTag(TagContext.java:31)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate$ExecutableTemplate.invokeTag(GroovyTemplate.java:380)
    at /test/selenium/AddCard.test.html.(line:3)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:229)
    ... 9 more
```

I wonder if something fundamentally changed with tags in Play 1.2 and I just overlooked it in the documentation or if this might be a bug. Any ideas on solving this riddle are welcome.

Comment: Could we see this :  at /test/selenium/AddCard.test.html.(line:3) ?

Comment: I added it. It just calls the tag in that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware that anything should have changed to stop this from working, so would expect this is a bug.

Comment: A few libraries have been upgraded but nothing that should break backward compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the #{fixture} tag. It will kill the internal stack when loading an yml file. See  https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/1026-using-tags-inside-tags-is-broken-since-play-121#ticket-1026-3.

As a workaround you can create a modified version of the fixture tag:

```
%{
    if(_delete == 'all') {
        play.test.Fixtures.deleteAll()
    } else if(_delete) {
        play.test.Fixtures.delete(_delete)
    }
}%

%{
    if(_load) {
        // Workaround (save the stack)
        stack = play.templates.TagContext.currentStack.get();

        play.test.Fixtures.load(_load)

        // Workaround (restore the stack)
        play.templates.TagContext.currentStack.set(stack);
    }
}%

%{
    if(_arg && _arg instanceof String) {
        try {
            play.Play.classloader.loadClass(_arg).newInstance()
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new play.exceptions.TagInternalException('Cannot apply ' + _arg + ' fixture because of ' + e.getClass().getName() + ', ' + e.getMessage())
        }
    }
%}
```